# Tratamento de exceções de uma InputBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, input, visual-basic-6

Estou fazendo um trabalho acadêmico onde eu tenho que pegar um dado digitado pelo Usuário e estou usando uma ***InputBox*** para tal.

Porem a InputBox exibe varios **erros** dos quais não estou sabendo tratar.

ao clicar **Cancelar** exibe o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Erro**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro **erro** que estou tentando **tratar** é ao clicar no (X) da *InputBox*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Erro**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso **tratar** esses erros?
Ou caso vocês tenham outras dicas de **melhores formas** de obter esse **input** do Usuário também gostaria de saber.

**Obrigado**.

Comment: O que faz a linha onde dá erro?

Comment: Pega o input digitado pelo usuario
valorRetorando = InputBox(Prompt, Titulo, respostaPadrao, XPos, YPos)

Comment: Pela imagem que postou o erro é na linha onde converte o valor digitado para inteiro.

Comment: mesmo digitando um valor Inteiro, ao clicar: cancelar ou o (x) ele exibe o erro.

Comment: O erro informa que o valor digitado(texto) não pode ser convertido para inteiro.

Comment: Não trate do sintoma, trate da doença. Quando tem um erro no código você o conserta e não tenta contorná-lo.

Comment: Consegui consertar pelo link que voce marcou @Maniero, fiz um try catch, Obrigado.

Comment: Se fez um `try-catch`não fez nada do que estava nos *links* que passei e fez o oposto do que eu comentei acima, tratou do sintoma, a doença continua lá.

Comment: Não entendi, qual seria a "doença"?

Comment: @ArthurLuiz não entendeu porque não leu os *links* que eu passei.